# Setting a Style for a Button, but changing some properties in UWP app

Tags: c#, wpf, uwp

I'd like to create a Style for a Button that has an Icon and a Textblock beside it.

Like this Pause Button here

[image: Pause button]

So for now I've just set up a Template inside the `Button.Content` property

```
<Button>
                    <Button.ContentTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition />
                                    <ColumnDefinition />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                <SymbolIcon Grid.Column="0" 
                                            Symbol="Pause" />
                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1"
                                           Text="Pause"/>

                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </Button.ContentTemplate>
                </Button>
```

This works for *this* button, but I'd like to **repeat the template for multiple buttons**. What if I have to do another Button, like a STOP button?

How can I create a Style, while changing the SymbolIcon and the Text property of the Textblock?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that with an AttachedProperty and overriding the Default-Style:

**AttachedProperty**

```
public static class ButtonAttachedProperties {

        public static void SetMySymbol(Button element, Symbol value) {
            element.SetValue(MySymbolProperty, value);
        }

        public static Symbol GetMySymbol(Button element) {
            return (Symbol) element.GetValue(MySymbolProperty);
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for MyProperty.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty MySymbolProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("MySymbol", typeof(Symbol), typeof(ButtonAttachedProperties), new PropertyMetadata(Symbol.Bullets));

    }
```

**ButtonStyle**

```
 <Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="DoubleContentStyle">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBorderThemeBrush}" />
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBorderThemeThickness}" />
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="12,4,12,4" />
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}" />
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="SemiBold" />
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                        <Grid>
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                                    <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Border"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonPointerOverForegroundThemeBrush}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Border"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonPressedBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonPressedForegroundThemeBrush}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Border"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonDisabledBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Border"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonDisabledBorderThemeBrush}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonDisabledForegroundThemeBrush}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualWhite"
                                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                                     To="1"
                                                     Duration="0" />
                                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualBlack"
                                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                                     To="1"
                                                     Duration="0" />
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused" />
                                    <VisualState x:Name="PointerFocused" />
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <Border x:Name="Border" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Margin="3">
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <SymbolIcon Symbol="{Binding Path=(vm:ButtonAttachedProperties.MySymbol), RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Mode=OneWay}"/>

                                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter" Grid.Column="1"
                                          Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                          ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}"
                                          ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                                          Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                          HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                          VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" 
                                          AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw"/>
                                </Grid>

                            </Border>
                            <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisualWhite"
                               IsHitTestVisible="False"
                               Stroke="{ThemeResource FocusVisualWhiteStrokeThemeBrush}"
                               StrokeEndLineCap="Square"
                               StrokeDashArray="1,1"
                               Opacity="0"
                               StrokeDashOffset="1.5" />
                            <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisualBlack"
                               IsHitTestVisible="False"
                               Stroke="{ThemeResource FocusVisualBlackStrokeThemeBrush}"
                               StrokeEndLineCap="Square"
                               StrokeDashArray="1,1"
                               Opacity="0"
                               StrokeDashOffset="0.5" />
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

**Usage**

```
 <Button Style="{StaticResource DoubleContentStyle}" Content="Pause" vm:ButtonAttachedProperties.MySymbol="Pause"/>
```

**My 2 cents**

I find this quite important to know. The `Symbol`-Enum hasn't a None or Default value. First i thought setting any default-value will do the trick, **but it wont compile**. So dont forget to set the Symbol on the Buttons you want to. If anyone can explain or has a good workaround, let us know!

Cheers!

Comment: I'm sorry if I may seem dunb, but have you actually rewrote the entire Style for the Button (VisualState and all)? Do you have to do that everytime you want to write a Style?

Comment: It seems so. I copied the style directly from microsoft. Maybe it will work somehow with ContentTemplate. But there you dont have TemplateBinding. So idk... Not pretty but working ;)